# Getting multiple variables with Mod Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^products/([^/\.]+)/?$ /product.php?$1
RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/?$ /category.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

the link i put into the browser is site.com/category/batteries/1/ where batteries is category and 1 would be the page.  However, my site only gets the category (so site.com/category/batteries/ works, but site.com/category/batteries/1/ returns a 404.)

category.php gets the value being passed in cat, but not the value in page.  I keep reading on this, but just can't understand where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the regex worked.  Just getting the text inbetween slashes instead of trying to find the digit gave me the desired result.

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /category.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a capturing group so `$2` is never set. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^products/(.*+)/?$ product.php?$1
RewriteRule ^category/(.*+)/(\d+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It just returns a 404... but I atleast see where I went wrong now.

Comment: Are you certain you have mod_rewrite enabled in apache? You should not get a 404 unless category.php does not exist

Comment: Yes.  It was working before if I didnt add the /1/... now it returns a 404 on both pages.

Comment: Don't think it will fix your issue but you had two !-d one should be !-f

Comment: Thanks... i only did that on here, but didn't notice.

Comment: Try my updated one, without the forward slash before product.php and category.php

Comment: Still returning a 404.